# how to add css classes to a component in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So basically what I am doing is iterating through an array of data and making some kind of list. What I want to achieve here is on clicking on a particular list item a css class should get attached.

**Iteration to make a list**

```
var sports = allSports.sportList.map((sport) => {
return (
  <SportItem icon= {sport.colorIcon} text = {sport.name} onClick={this.handleClick()} key= {sport.id}/>
)
})
```

**A single list item**

```
   <div className="display-type icon-pad ">
      <div className="icons link">
        <img className="sport-icon" src={icon}/>
      </div>
      <p className="text-center">{text}</p>
    </div>
```

I am not able to figure out what to do with handleClick so that If I click on a particular list it gets highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a separate [state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) variable for every item that can be selected and use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library to conditionally manipulate classes as facebook [recommends](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html).

Edit: ok, you've mentioned that only 1 element can be selected at a time,it means that we only need to store which one of them was selected  (I'm going to use the selected item's id). And also I've noticed a typo in your code, you need to link the function when you declare a component, not call it

```
<SportItem onClick={this.handleClick} ...
```

(notice how `handleClick` no longer contains `()`).

And now we're going to pass the element's id along with the event to the `handleClick` handler using [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) - `bind` method:

```
<SportItem onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,sport.id} ...
```

And as I said we want to store the selected item's id in the state, so the `handleClick` could look like:

```
handleClick(id,event){
this.setState({selectedItemId: id})
...
}
```

Now we need to pass the `selectedItemId` to `SportItem` instances so they're aware of the current selection: `<SportItem selectedItemId={selectedItemId} ...`.Also, don't forget to attach the `onClick={this.handleClick}` callback to where it needs to be, invoking which is going to trigger the change of the state in the parent:

```
<div onClick={this.props.onClick} className={classNames('foo', { myClass: this.props.selectedItemId == this.props.key}); // => the div will always have 'foo' class but 'myClass' will be added only if this is the element that's currently selected}>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be a new variable for every item, it could just be a single array called `selected: []`. Also classnames library isn't necessary, but can helpful in some cases.

Comment: Yes, of course you could also do it that way. I just provided a trivial solution that's easy to understand. Once he does that, i'm sure he'll refractor it into something more efficient

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any working example to do that? I am quite new in react.

Comment: What I want to achieve here is at one time only one time should be highighted

Comment: Hey Igorsvee in the last expression how are you accessing the state of parent from child "this.state.selectedItemId" ?

Comment: I wrote it as if you didn't have a separate component for div blocks, but you do have it (my bad).I've edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to highlight the particular list item it's way better to call the `handleClick` function on the list item itself, and you can add CSS classes more accurately with this approach,

here is my sample code to implement the single list component

```
var SingleListItem = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        isClicked: false
    };
},
handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({
        isClicked: true
    })
},
render: function() {
    var isClicked = this.state.isClicked;
    var style = {
        'background-color': ''
    };
    if (isClicked) {
        style = {
            'background-color': '#D3D3D3'
        };
    }
    return (
        <li onClick={this.handleClick} style={style}>{this.props.text}</li>
    );
  }
});
```