# Adding a CSS class to a JSX in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I wanted to add an '*active*' class to a menu element, written in **ReactJS**. I tried doing it with the conventional JS method, but it failed. A click on any <li> tag, should result is removal of the '*active*' class from all the <li>, and **retain/ add** it only to the one list tag in which the click was triggered.

**Note**: I know it may seem very naive on my part, but I'm just starting with ReactJS. Please ignore the stupidity.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';

class Sidebar extends Component{

render(){
    return(
        <div className="sidebarContainer p-2">                
            <div className="mainMenu">
                <ul className="levelOne pl-0">
                    <li className="mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle active" id="MenuTitle1">
                        ...
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle" id="MenuTitle2" onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this,'MenuTitle2')}>
                        ...
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle" id="MenuTitle3" onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this,'MenuTitle3')}>
                        ...
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>               
        </div>
    );
}

clickMenu(id){
    // Add class 'active' on the clicked <li>, and remove from all other <li>
}
}


 export default Sidebar;
```

I saw a similar question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108858/how-to-add-css-classes-to-a-component-in-react)**, but that couldn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is, store the id of clicked item in `state` variable and put the check with className. If item's id is same as state value then only assign the className `active`.

Write it like this:

```
class Sidebar extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            activeItem: 'MenuTitle1'
        }
    }

    clickMenu(id){
        // Add class 'active' on the clicked <li>, and remove from all other <li>
        this.setState({
            activeItem: id,
        })
    }

    getClassName(id) {
        if(id === this.state.activeItem) return 'mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle active'
        return 'mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle'
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="sidebarContainer p-2">                
                <div className="mainMenu">
                    <ul className="levelOne pl-0">
                        <li
                            id="MenuTitle1"
                            className={this.getClassName('MenuTitle1')}
                            onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this,'MenuTitle1')}>
                            ...
                        </li>
                        <li 
                            id="MenuTitle2"
                            className={this.getClassName('MenuTitle2')}
                            onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this,'MenuTitle2')}>
                            ...
                        </li>
                        <li 
                            id="MenuTitle3"
                            className={this.getClassName('MenuTitle3')}
                            onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this,'MenuTitle3')}>
                            ...
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>               
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the state for clicked menu item:

```
clickMenu(id){
 this.setState({activeMenu: id})
}
```

Then, define className like this:

```
className={
  this.state.activeMenu == id {/* eg. "MenuTitle1" */}
  ? 'mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle active' 
  : 'mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Bhojendra suggested store datas linked to your display inside your state then when you want to update the display of your component use the method setState, this will  trigger render again (react style).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activeMenuId: "MenuTitle1"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebarContainer p-2">
        <div className="mainMenu">
          <ul className="levelOne pl-0">
            <li className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.activeMenuId === "MenuTitle1" ? "active" : ""}`} id="MenuTitle1" onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, 'MenuTitle1')}>
              1
                    </li>
            <li className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.activeMenuId === "MenuTitle2" ? "active" : ""}`} id="MenuTitle2" onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, 'MenuTitle2')}>
              2
                    </li>
            <li className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.activeMenuId === "MenuTitle3" ? "active" : ""}`}  id="MenuTitle3" onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, 'MenuTitle3')}>
              3
                    </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  clickMenu(id) {
    // Add class 'active' on the clicked <li>, and remove from all other <li>
    this.setState({activeMenuId: id});
  }
}


export default Sidebar;
ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of just make using `initialstate` and `setState`.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    class Sidebar extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialState = {
          MenuTitle1: "active",
          MenuTitle2: "",
          MenuTitle3: ""
        };
        this.state = this.initialState;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="sidebarContainer p-2">
            <div className="mainMenu">
              <ul className="levelOne pl-0">
                <li
                  className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.MenuTitle1} `}
                  id="MenuTitle1"
                  onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, "MenuTitle1")}
                >
                  one
                </li>
                <li
                  className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.MenuTitle2}`}
                  id="MenuTitle2"
                  onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, "MenuTitle2")}
                >
                  two
                </li>
                <li
                  className={`mb-3 pl-2 menuTitle ${this.state.MenuTitle3}`}
                  id="MenuTitle3"
                  onClick={this.clickMenu.bind(this, "MenuTitle3")}
                >
                  three
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

      clickMenu(id) {
        this.setState(this.initialState);
        this.setState({
          [id]: "active"
        });
      }
    }

    export default Sidebar;
```